# a lot of questions on composition, should we make a wiki or resource reference?

Tags: discussion, support

I was even one of those people asking a question of this kind compelled by the need of finding a good way, or variations of ways on make compositions.

What you think if we can put up a wiki of possible compositions, or example on compositions or reading on compositions so we can make reference to it for all those question related to it?

I am sure that with a common effort of our knowledge we can come out with something really interesting, inspiring and useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SE format does allow for wikis tied to specific tags that can be created and updated by users that meet certain requirements. Clicking on a tag anywhere in the interface kicks off a search for only those questions that use that particular tag. At the top of that page, there is a link to create and view the wiki for that tag. The tag wiki typically isn't as robust as a traditional wiki (no multiple pages, just a single page), but it is utilized on Stackoverflow for FAQs, links to other resources, and the like.

The trick here is that [there is only one question that uses the composition tag](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/composition) at the time of this writing.

Comment: Thank you I was unaware of this dynamic.